# How to upgrade splunk 6.1.4 to 6.5 have license

Tags: upgrade, updates, splunk

I am using splunk 6.1.4 with license, now I want to upgrade splunk 6.5 still holds this license. 
I tried upgrading to 6.5.9 but it does not receive the license.

Can you help me! Please!
Best regards,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Licenses don't change with releases.  Your 6.1.4 license will work with 6.5.9.  If, for some reason, the license is not present after upgrading simply re-add your 6.1.4 license key.

Comment: i upgraded to 6.5.9 but still error: "License payload hash does not match saved hash. failed to load license from file: license.lic, err. cannot find non-empty stack=enterprise for pool=auto_generated_pool_enterprise,skipping"

Comment: Perhaps your license file somehow has become corrupted.  Try installing an earlier copy of the file or request a new license file from Splunk.

Comment: i used license public on network, so dont request new license from Splunk. :(

Comment: Splunk does not have public licenses.  You should remove that license file and restart Splunk to run it under the Free license, but you'll be limited to 500MB/day of indexing.